# Waiting for parts -- should I leave this question open?

Tags: discussion

I posted [a question about attaching a basket to my cruiser](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/369/wald-basket-legs-too-short-for-cruiser-how-can-i-install-the-basket), and received a couple of answers. I'm currently waiting on parts, and it looks like I'm going to have to wait a couple of weeks until I know what worked best.

Should I just accept one of these answers as the best answer, or should I wait until I know what worked? I suspect that [Dustin's answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/369/wald-basket-legs-too-short-for-cruiser-how-can-i-install-the-basket/425#425) will be at least my short-term solution, but I don't yet know. I don't want to award the correct answer and have to "take it away" later if that turned out to be incorrect.

Does the fact that I'm in this situation mean I should have crafted the question better? If so, how could I have done it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a comment to say you're waiting on parts and that you'll report back by way of comment, accepting an answer or adding a new answer once you get the parts.

That way, everyone knows the answers aren't ignored, tho thats obvious from the comment exchange, and also you avoid having to award and possibly retract a correct answer.

Comment: +1 Agreed, make sure it's clear the solution is pending. I imagine this may happen often with maintenance questions... "Hold on while I go try this out..."

Comment: In fact, it's probably better to edit the original question because where there are many comments, such as in this example, the comment you add may not be visible.